# How to scatter an array of strings in MPI C++

Tags: c++, mpi

What I want to do is to run a basic MapReduce operation over some strings. I want to:

1. Distribute (equally) a list of strings to all my processes,
2. In the processes: Map the received strings to objects of a custom class (e.g. `WordWithFrequency`),
3. Gather the objects and send them to the processes again for further operations.

It should be a simple task, but I couldn't find a way to do it properly. Here is my broken code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>

...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Find out the process rank and the world size
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    vector<string> words = { "a", "bc", "d" };
    const int wordsLength = words.size();
    const int wordsPerProcess = wordsLength / world_size;

    string *subWords = new string[wordsPerProcess];
    MPI_Scatter(&words, wordsPerProcess, MPI_CHAR, subWords, wordsPerProcess, ???customDataType???, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("Process %d got words:\n", world_rank);
    for (int i = 0; i < wordsPerProcess; ++i) {
        cout << subWords[i] << endl;
    }

    ...
```

Output is some funny letters that changes from execution to execution:

```
Process 0 got words:
�R


Process 1 got words:
```

Comment: Do try and use things like `std::vector` in preference to `new[]`. It'll make your life *significantly* easier since memory management issues are dramatically reduced.

Comment: @tadman I think (actually, I'm sure) the problem is with `MPI_Scatter`, not with the array. I'm doing something completely wrong here, but I couldn't find any single example of string scattering on the internet.

ps. `std::vector` didn't help.

Comment: It's not going to magically fix all your problems in this particular case, but it'll be useful in the long term since you won't waste days tracking down memory leaks.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747287/odd-even-transposition-sort-with-strings-mpi-c Long story short, `MPI_Scatter()` does not work with an array of pointers. If you really want to use `MPI_Scatter()` you should use a 2D array of `char` (e.g. an array of fixed length "strings")

Comment: I solved my problem by using Boost.MPI which can scatter a vector of strings without any extra work. It also makes it super easy to serialize custom objects. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

It's a really easy task with Boost.MPI:

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment.
    mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
    mpi::communicator world;

    vector<string> words = { "foo", "bar", "baz", "..." };
    const int wordCount = words.size();
    const int wordsPerProcess = wordCount / world.size();
    vector<vector<string> > wordsByProcess(world.size(), vector<string>());
    for (int j = 0; j < world.size(); ++j) {
        for (int k = 0, wordIndex = j * wordsPerProcess + k;
             k < wordsPerProcess && wordIndex < wordCount; ++k, ++wordIndex) {
            wordsByProcess[j].push_back(words[wordIndex]);
        }
    }

    vector<string> subWords;
    mpi::scatter(world, wordsByProcess, subWords, 0);
    // subWords is equal to wordsByProcess[world.rank()] here in every process.
```

Scatter takes a vector of elements, which is indexed by the process number to which the corresponding value will be sent. For more details, see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/scatter.html